# how to get class of a variable in R using loop?

Tags: r

I have data frame in R with four columns and I am trying to get class of each variable using for loop, depending on a class of variable I could write a further code. Below is the data frame.

```
   var1 var2 var3 var4
1     1    a    a    s
2     2    g    a    s
3     3    b         s
4     4    n    s    s
5    NA    m    f    f
6     6    r    g    v
7     7    t         b
8     8         j     
9     9    y    i    g
10   10    h    i    t
```

As of now I have tried below code but it is giving NULL for a class of variable

```
for (i in names(df)){
  print(names(df[i]))
  name <- names(df[i])
  print(class(df$name))
}
```

Result with above code:

```
[1] "var1"
[1] "NULL"
[1] "var2"
[1] "NULL"
[1] "var3"
[1] "NULL"
[1] "var4"
[1] "NULL"
```

Expecting Result

```
    [1] "var1"
    [1] "integer"
    [1] "var2"
    [1] "factor"
    [1] "var3"
    [1] "factor"
    [1] "var4"
    [1] "integer"
```

Requesting your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `data.frame`s are really just a `list` of columns, I do this often  using `lapply`:

```
lapply(df, class)
```

As for the `for` loop you have in the example, when you call `df$name`, R is trying to find the column called "name". Instead, you want `df[, name]`:

```
for (i in names(df)){
  name <- names(df[i])
  print(name)
  print(class(df[, name]))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using mtcars as an example:

```
for (i in names(mtcars)){
    print(names(mtcars[i]))
    name <- names(mtcars[i])
    print(class(mtcars[,i]))
    }
```